# How to define data for REACT that comes from a web site that return JSON

Tags: reactjs

I have this piece of REACT code I'm trying to make work without having to define the structure of the data in the state line

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class App extends Component {
  
  state = {
    list:     { Names:  [{Sname:"Peter",Given:"Tony"}]      }    
  };

  renderItems = () => {
    const data = this.state.list;
    const junk1 = data.Names.map((nm) => (
      <tr><td>{nm.Given}</td><td>{nm.Sname}</td></tr>
    ));
    return <table>{junk1}</table>;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <h4>
        {"Test ->"}{this.renderItems()}{"<--"} <p />
      </h4>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {    
    var that = this;
    var url = 'https://localhost:60000/demo/test'
  
    const  requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ Param: '80' })
    };

    fetch(url, requestOptions)
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
          throw new Error("Bad response from server");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        that.setState({ list: data });
      });
  }
}

export default App;
```

I'm wanting to define the state like this

```
  state = {
    list:     {}
  };
```

where I don't have to create a skeleton structure. I have also tried [] with the same effect.

They each return a message similar to

```
Property 'Names' does not exist on type '{}'.  TS2339
```

The code with "data.Names.map" thinks Names doesn't exist (but it does at runtime but fails anyway).

Checking examples on the web hasn't helped.

Any suggestions on what I have done wrong ?

EDIT:
If I define list as "list: JSON.parse('{}')" then I can assign my JSON to it in the callback, and I can iterate over the data like

```
var i,s;
s = '';
for (i=0;i<data.Patients.length-1;i++){
  s = s + data.Patients[i].Sname + ', ' + data.Patients[i].Given + ' | ';
}
return <div>{s}</div>;
```

There must be a better way.

Comment: state.list has the initial value of `{}` - therefore Names does not exist (when in `renderItems()`)

Comment: to resolve, you need to `if (!data) return null` in `renderItems()`

Comment: How does the data look like?

Comment: I realise Names doesn't exist in the declaration, I think what I'm looking for is how to define list as any (like "list: any") which I think would then let be assign the JSON to it.